# django debug toolbar showing SQL as None

Tags: django, django-debug-toolbar

We use the django-debug-toolbar on two replated apps, one serving our legacy django app and the other serving our newer API. Recently, the debug-toolbar on the API has been showing SQL queries as None (see screen shot)
[image]

The other app is working as expected.

The debugsqlshell which ships with the debug-toolbar is also reporting queries as None:

```
In [8]: user = User.objects.last()
None [0.85ms]

In [9]:
```

rather than showing the queries as expected, and as seen here (working on the legacy app side):

```
In [3]: user = User.objects.last()
SELECT @@SQL_AUTO_IS_NULL [1.96ms]
SELECT `auth_user`.`id`,
       `auth_user`.`password`,
       `auth_user`.`last_login`,
       `auth_user`.`is_superuser`,
       `auth_user`.`username`,
       `auth_user`.`first_name`,
       `auth_user`.`last_name`,
       `auth_user`.`is_staff`,
       `auth_user`.`is_active`,
       `auth_user`.`date_joined`,
       `auth_user`.`email`
FROM `auth_user`
ORDER BY `auth_user`.`id` DESC
LIMIT 1 [10.00ms]

In [4]:
```

I have checked some obvious things.

- No settings have changed recently on the affected app, and in
  particular, middlewares have not been reordered in any way, which
  seems like a potential cause of the problem.
- The debug-toolbar has not been updated recently, and updating the 
  debug-toolbar to the current version does not affect the situation.
- I am able to see queries using the CaptureQueriesContext (from 
  django.test.utils) when running in a test context, but not in the 
  debugsqlshell.

I'm currently trying to find the point in history where this broke. I would appreciate any suggestions for potential causes, to help localize and fix this issue.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue with django debug toolbar.
I downgraded mysqlclient from version 1.3.14 to 1.3.13 and it's working now.

Comment: Verified: downgrading to 1.3.13 worked for me as well. Will file a bug ticket on django debug toolbar.

Comment: Installing 1.3.13 was found impossible on Windows (compilation errors). Using 1.3.12 helped me.

Answer (score 1):

Guys from GitHub recommend updating Django to v2.1.5.
Mostly, an upgrade is a better solution than downgrading. It works for me.

https://github.com/jazzband/django-debug-toolbar/issues/1124#issuecomment-452407342